# going back to android app from window.open browser

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-build, phonegap

I have posted a form to on online url in my phonegap app. The online url opens in the app and it shows me the posted data. But now how do I go back to my app using some link etc. I am using the following code but in vain :

**showdata.php**

```
 <?php



var_dump($_POST);


?>

//this doesn't works
<a onclick="close(); return false;">Close me</a>
```

in my app **index.html** :

```
   <form action="http://mywebsite.com/showdata.php" id=dataform">

 <input type="text" value="itemname" value="CPU">

</form>

<script>    

    document.getElementById('dataform').submit();

</script>
```

**UPDATE :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                                            var mapForm = document.getElementById("dataform");

                                            var map=cordova.InAppBrowser.open("","_blank","location=yes");

                                            if (map) 
                                            {

                                                document.getElementById("dataform").submit();

                                            } 
                                            else 
                                            { 

                                                alert('You must allow popups for this map to work.');

                                            }




                                         </script>
```

Comment: Is using window.open  not the same thing. The functionality is same, so I din't feel like using it because I din't got any differences in using window.open as compared to inappbrowser

Comment: My recommendation is to use the plugin, because the cordova/phonegap is specific to use plugins

Answer (score 1):

You can use [inappbrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) cordova plugin.

Here is example of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                 // Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open('http://paypal.me/xxxzzzyyy/5', '_blank', 'location=yes');
}

</script>
```

You can also call link onclick and there is close button which makes you back to app.

Comment: so will I be able to close this window using a link  and reach back into my app ?

Comment: @sqlchild Yes, because plugin is inside application, its not like default mobile browser ( chrome or something )

Comment: ok , also you have used window.open  instead of cordova.InAppBrowser.open() ?  so there is no need to use cordova object ?

Comment: is there no need to the use cordova.InAppBrowser.open() function ?

Comment: @sqlchild Just read plugin specs first.. **Existing window.open() calls can use the InAppBrowser window, by replacing window.open:**

`window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;`

Comment: Ok i have implemented your code, but now the window opens and closes automatically : Please refer  to my update

Comment: would be great if you could please help me out in my code

Comment: also, the form action is on my online website . example : mywebsite.com

Comment: @sqlchild What exactly you are trying to do ? Show some results or ?

Comment: i have a link in my app, on clicking on which the form 'dataform' is posted to my online website url :www.mywebsite.com/itemlist.php , wherein the item chosen is shown and then the user can pay, so i need to post  this form to my online url and open that url  in my app in such a way that after payment user can click BACK TO HOME button and the app refreshes and shows that the PAYMENT SUCCESSFUL

Comment: So you need to make ajax call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172302/discussion-between-sqlchild-and-proofzy).

Comment: i need to post data to a url which then posts data to another external url, how can this be done via jax

Comment: @sqlchild lets move to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172302/discussion-between-sqlchild-and-proofzy